# R working the tsDyn and Time series

Tags: r, time-series

Hello I am trying to work with the tsDyn packages to fit time series. Save me a lot of time if I could get this package to work correctly.

I am working with data that looks like this:

```
          time   change    high      low   slope13 slope50 slope200 prediction
1 2.008082e+13 -0.00150 0.00860 -0.00420 288.46154  185.20    52.85         NA
2 2.008082e+13  0.00160 0.00570 -0.00540  90.84615  178.22    55.10         NA
3 2.008082e+13 -0.00320 0.00020 -0.00409  42.07692  181.00    55.25         NA
4 2.008082e+13 -0.00310 0.00330 -0.00010  36.92308  180.80    61.60         NA
5 2.008082e+13 -0.00156 0.00770 -0.00140 -18.46154  172.60    59.25         NA
6 2.008082e+13  0.00416 0.00176 -0.00292 -18.84615  171.56    58.27         NA
```

The time column is the column that contains the time. It looks like 20080817210000 YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.

When trying to use any of the functions on the data I get an error.

```
only univariate time series are allowed
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here any help would be appreciated.

An example:

```
> mt4nnetTS <- nnetTs(mt4, m= 2, size= 3)
 Error in nlar.struct(x = x, m = m, d = d, steps = steps, series = series) : 
   only univariate time series are allowed
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what type of object is mt4?  Is that the name of the dataframe you pasted in?  If you do str(mt4) what is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely answer is that mt4 is an object with multiple columns/variables and the function `nnetTs()` does not know which one to use.

Assuming mt4 is a dataframe and it is what you showed us as sample data, you could do something like this:

```
mt4nnetTS <- nnetTs(mt4$change, m= 2, size= 3)
```

Here, we indicate we want to model a variable named change in an object named mt4.